# Is it possible to point to array of named ranges with INDEX reference form?

Tags: excel

I'm keeping data in several equally sized arrays saved as named ranges Arr1, Arr2, Arr3 etc. I want to look up things from any these arrays with INDEX or CHOOSE wrapped inside another INDEX e.g. by going INDEX(INDEX((Arr1;Arr2;Arr3);;MATCH...);2;2)

As my list of arrays grows large and I need to apply my INDEX/CHOOSE-MATCH many places, I'd like to avoid repetition and store the names of my named ranges in another array or table, let's call it Arr_list.

Is it possible to substitute the reference part, i.e. '(Arr1;Arr2;Arr3)' of an INDEX formula with a call to the Arr_list array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do this without the INDIRECT function(which is volatile, and may slow down workbook with large ranges) is to make your Arr_List into one array using the colon Range operator, or the comma union operator.

I show an example of it below with the Master named ranges themselves as named ranges.

[image: The Names manager]

You may form a Union like so:

`=Name,Age,Sales,Gender` OR

`=name:Age:Sales:Gender`

The comma/Union way is referenced with the 2nd form of INDEX which takes a reference, and then gets the area as parameter like:

`=INDEX(Master2, 2, 1, 4)` to get Gender.

The Colon/Range way is referenced by the 1st form of Index:

`=INDEX(Master, 2, 4)`

Comment: Thanks for this solution also. I'm thrilled to see various ways to resolve my problem. I can confirm this also worked for me but I went with BigBen's solution in this case. My apologies for not replying earlier, <insert long, boring excuse> :-)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `INDEX(Arr_list)` in `INDIRECT` - then the outermost `INDEX` understands the result of `INDEX(ARr_list)` refers to a named range.

An example:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(INDEX(ArrayList,2)),2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the elegant answer. I've implemented it and it works like a charm and dramatically shortens my formula \(^_^)/

Comment: Also, my greatest apologies for taking so long to reply and test your solution! I really appreciate your help.